# jx fails with BadRequestException 400 Invalid value

Tags: jenkins-x

While executing jx create cluster gke, I run into the following error.

```
No bucket name provided for long term storage, creating a new one
The bucket gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3 does not exist so lets create it
Error creating bucket: Creating gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3/...
BadRequestException: 400 Invalid Value, failed to run 'gsutil mb -l (unset) -p dnpjx2 gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3' command in directory '', output: 'Creating gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3/...
BadRequestException: 400 Invalid Value'
ERROR: error creating cluster configuring Long Term Storage: enabling long term storage on GKE: there was a problem creating the bucket dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3 in the GKE Project dnpjx2: failed to run 'gsutil mb -l (unset) -p dnpjx2 gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3' command in directory '', output: 'Creating gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3/...
BadRequestException: 400 Invalid Value'
error: configuring Long Term Storage: enabling long term storage on GKE: there was a problem creating the bucket dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3 in the GKE Project dnpjx2: failed to run 'gsutil mb -l (unset) -p dnpjx2 gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3' command in directory '', output: 'Creating gs://dnpjx2-lts-89ae2b2c-6234-40b6-ac1b-4da9388493b3/...
BadRequestException: 400 Invalid Value'
```

The following things have been verified/additional info

- using the full gsutil command in the command line gives me a syntax errror
- executing the gsutil command without -l (unset) on the command line works.
- In the jx command, I set the --region parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug in jx version 2.0.1094

When picking the pre-selected value, it is not taken. One has to select change the selection at least once.